# Norm inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

While trying to compute a quotient space, the next problem has come to my attention:

> Let $x=(x_j)_j$ and $y=(y_j)_j$ be two complex convergent sequences such that $x-y=(x_j-y_j)_j$, is a constant sequence.
>   $$
> \text{Note that $x-y$ is a constant sequence if and only if $x_j-x_{j+1}= y_j-y_{j+1}$ for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$.}
> $$
>   Consider the sequence $z=(y_j-y_{j+1})_j$. What is the order relation between $$
> \| x \|_\infty = \sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} | x_j | \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \| z \|_\infty= \sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} | y_j - y_{j+1}| \ \ \text{ ?}
> $$

My guess is that $\| x \|_\infty \geq \| z \|_\infty$. However, I can not prove it, so I am starting to think I may be wrong and no order relation can be obtained. My guess is not random, I have come up whit a few examples where it actually holds like the next ones:
$$
x=(1,1/2,1/3, \cdots ) \\
y=(1/2, 0 , -1/6 , \cdots)
$$
Clearly $x-y = (1/2, 1/2, 1/2, \cdots)$ and if $z=(y_j-y_{j+1})_j$ then 
$$
\| x \|_\infty=1 \geq 1/2=\| z \|_\infty
$$
Another example is obtained from the one above by changing $x$ and $y$ roles, that is since $y-x =(-1/2, - 1/2, - 1/2, \cdots)$, if now $z=(x_j-x_{j+1})_j$ then 
$$
\|y\|_\infty = 1/2 = \| z \|_\infty
$$

So, my question here is could someone help me on how to prove that my guess is correct or give a counterexample when $\|x\|_\infty < \| z \|_\infty$ ? I would appreciate it very much. Also if you think more details of the original problem can help let me know so I can make an edit.

Comment: $x = y = (1,-1,0,0,\dotsc)$.

Comment: The idea is that y is a translation x; y does not really play any role in your question. Just look x and the difference $x_{j+1}-x_j$. You want to make the difference "big" while keeping x "small".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, I believe it is false.

Consider $x=(50, -50, 50, -50, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...)$ and $y=(40, -60, 40, -60, -10, -10, -10,...)$.  Then $x-y=(10, 10, ...)$ and is constant.  $z=(-100, -100, -100, -70, -20, -20, -20, ...)$ so $\Vert z\Vert_{\infty} = 100$ and $\Vert x\Vert_{\infty} = 50$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will soon post a question about the original problem, Its a long one and my proof depended a lot on my guess here being correct, so its wrong. I hope I come up with something new soon. Thanks again.

Comment: This is the original problem: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281099/compute-quotient-space-isometry-part 
who gave birth to the question you answered above, I hope you can take a look and let me know if you come up with something.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the counterexample:

Let $x=(-1,1,0,0,0,...)$ and $x=y$. Then $z=(2,-1,0,0,0,...)$ and $||x||_\infty=1$, while $||z||_\infty=2$.

The idea is not very different from Travis' answer.

Comment: This is a good answer too (like @DanielFischer's comment).  More elegant than my solution.  (I got to thinking to get a big difference I needed "big" numbers... it is un-necessarily large; it's just what I came up with while very quickly experimenting).

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos  This is the original problem: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281099/compute-quotient-space-isometry-part 
who gave birth to the question you answered above, I hope you can take a look and let me know if you come up with something.