# Compute Quotient Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces

I have been struggling with this computation for a while now. I thought I was almost there, but it now results I still have nothing. So here is the initial problem:

> Let $c=\left\{ (x_j)_j \subset \mathbb{C}: (x_j)_j \ \text{is a convergent sequence }\right\}$ equipped with the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, and $Y=\left\{ (x_j)_j \in c : (x_j)_j \ \text{is a constant sequence }\right\}$. Compute $c/Y$, that is find the Banach space to whom $c/Y$ is isometrically isomorphic.
>
> Three things one must know to tackle this problem:
>
> **1)** The equivalence relation consider here is $x \sim y$ iff $\ x-y \in Y$
>
> **2)** The quotient space is $c/Y = \{ [x]: x \in c \}$
>
> **3)** The norm in $c/Y$ is given by $\|[x]\|=\inf_{y \in [x]} \{\|y\|_\infty\}$

**My advances:** I already have proved that $Y \subset c$ is a closed subspace, so indeed $c/Y$ is a Banach space. Lets now consider $c_0=\left\{ (x_j)_j \in c: x_j \to 0 \text{ as } j \to \infty \right\}$, and define $S \subset c_0$ as follows
$$
S= \left\{ (z_j)_j \in c_0 : \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} z_j \ \text{ converges in } \mathbb{C} \right\}.
$$
I have fisrt conjectured that $c/Y \cong S$, and by defining $\Phi: c/Y \to S$ as
$$
\Phi([(x_j)_j]) : = (x_j-x_{j+1})_j \ \ \ \text{for } \ \ (x_j)_j \in c
$$
I successfully showed that $\Phi$ is **i)Linear**, **ii)Injective** and **iii) Onto**, however, I could not prove the **iv)Isometry** part.

**EDIT:** I now know thanks to @Jochen comment that proving **iv)** is impossible since $S$ is not it self a Banach space, and I thought it was, so $c/Y$ and $S$ are only isomorphic, but they are not the same Banach space.

> So my question now changes, since $S$ is not isometrically isomorphic to $c/Y$ which Banach space must be? It is correct to still looking for a $c_0$ subspace ot it might be something totally different.I am clueless since all my bets where on $S$. I would appreciate it very much any help given here.

Comment: $S$ isn't closed in $c_0$. It is a dense subspace.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you very much for pointing this out, that is why I was not able to prove the isometry, and indeed for each $n$, $(1/j^{1+1/n})_j \in S$ but the limit $(1/j)_j \not\in S$ so $S$ is not closed, my bad! I have now make an edit considering this. Thanks again but now I am even more lost than I was, what Banach space you think $c/Y$ must be? I hope you or someone can come up with something

Comment: Look at $F:c \to c_0$, $(x_n)_n \mapsto (x_n - x_\infty)_n$ where $x_\infty=\lim x_n$. $F$ vanishes on $Y$ and thus induces a well-defined map $c/Y\to c_0$ which is easily seen to be a bijection.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks again. I clearly see that $F$ is a bijection, let me try to prove that is also an isometry and I would be done. If is not I'll let you know.

Comment: @Jochen Well It looks like $F:c/Y\to c_0$ is NOT an isometry :( . Take for example $$
x=(1,1/2,1/3, \cdots ) \\
y=(1/2, 0 , -1/6 , \cdots)
$$
We got that $x - y \in Y$ thus $y \in [x]$, however since $x_\infty=0$ we see that
$$
\| [x] \| = \inf_{z \in [x] } \{ \| z\|_\infty\} \leq \| y \|_\infty=\frac{1}{2} < 1= \| x\|_\infty = \sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} |x_j| = \sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} |x_j-x_\infty|=\|F([x]) \|_\infty
$$
Thus $F$ is not an isometry since there exist $x \in c$ such that $\| [x] \| < \|F([x]) \|_\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well-known (and easy to see) that $c/Y$ is isomorphic to $c_0$.  So we just need to renorm $c_0$ so that the natural map between them is an isometry.  In fact, the norm $|||\cdot|||$ will do, where
\begin{equation*}|||(x_n)|||=\frac{1}{2}\sup_{m,n}|x_n-x_m|.\end{equation*}
Notice that for any $(x_n)\in c_0$ we have
\begin{equation*}\|(x_n)\|_{c/Y}=\inf_{x\in\mathbb{C}}\|(x_n)-x\|_\infty=\inf_{r\in\mathbb{C}}\sup_n|x_n-r|.\end{equation*}
For any $m,n$, let $r(m,n)$ be the midpoint between $x_m$ and $x_n$, so that
\begin{equation*}\sup_{m,n}|x_n-x_m|=2\sup_{m,n}|x_n-r(m,n)|\geq 2\inf_{r\in\mathbb{C}}\sup_n|x_n-r|.\end{equation*}
For the reverse inequality, notice that for any $r\in\mathbb{C}$ we have
\begin{equation*}\sup_{m,n}|x_n-x_m|\leq\sup_{m,n}(|x_n-r|+|x_m-r|)\leq 2\sup_n|x_n-r|\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{equation*}\sup_{m,n}|x_n-x_m|\leq 2\inf_{r\in\mathbb{C}}\sup_n|x_n-r|.\end{equation*}
Thus, $c/Y$ is isometric to $(c_0,|||\cdot|||)$ via the natural map.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot ! I never thought on changing the $c_0$ norm. I haven't read it carefully yet but I assume that by the natural map you mean the one who assigns $(x_n - x_\infty)_n$ to each $(x_n)_n\in c$ with $x_\infty =\lim_n x_n$, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the subspace of $c$ of convergent sequences $x = (x_1,x_2,\dotsc)$ satisfying $\sup x  + \inf x = 0$.  Let $y_\alpha$ denote the constant sequence $\alpha, \alpha, \dotsc$. Let $h(x)$ denote the number $\sup(x) + \inf(x) \over 2$ Then the map $c/Y \rightarrow S$ given by $[x] \mapsto x - y_{h(x)}$ is an isometry onto $S$.